# Limits on difference between a perfect square and a perfect cube?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, square-numbers

Are there known bounds on these differences?

$378661^2-5234^3=17$ is the best I found for small numbers, which suggests to me that there's maybe a lower bound that goes as the cube root of the number being cubed, since $17^3 < 5234 < 18^3$. To be specific, I'm wondering if there really is such a lower bound, or if the difference can be arbitrarily small for large values.

On a side note, it also seems to be common to find nearby pairs with very close differences, e.g.

$3006688^3-5213538037^2=39303 \\
5213891773^2-3006824^3=39305$

This only occurs when the mean of those differences is a cube ($39304=34^3$), so I suspect there's some obvious reason for it.

Comment: Note that $5213891773-5213538037=9\cdot 34^3$ and $3006824-3006688=4\cdot 34$

Comment: What about things like $27^2 = 9^3$, $125^2 = 25^3$, and so on? $(a^3)^2 = (a^2)^3$?

Comment: I should have mentioned that: I omit equal cases as trivial.

Comment: $a^2 - b^3 = c$ is a Pell-like equation (since $a^2 - b^3 = (a - b\sqrt{b})(a + b\sqrt{b})$) so methods for solving Pell-like equations apply here.

Comment: Not clear what your criterion is or what "best I've found for small numbers" means, but here are some more: $736844^2 = 8158^3+24$, $1138^2 = 109^3+15$, $312^2 = 46^3+8$.

Comment: I do not understand what numbers you are searching, but I guess there is no smaller positive  lower bound than $3^2-2^3=1$ if you exclude $0^2-0^3 = 0.$

Comment: @mindloss  This should be useful : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall%27s_conjecture

Comment: @Peter That's exactly what I was looking for, thanks!